# Why the event triggerd twice to a controller method from jsp in abaxx framework?

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to abaxx framework. I have a question regarding event handling from jsp to controller through abaxx framework.

**Problem statement:**

on click of the button event triggers from the jsp page and control come to controller but the controller methods executes twice, because of this I am facing some condition failure. could any one please help me to understand how this request response control is handled in abaxx framework?

```
**sample code follows below**
```

In JSP

```
<jpos:button event="calculate" html="id='calculateButton' onclick=\"disableExcludeInterest(false); deactiveButton('okButton'); return validationBefCalculate();\"" formVariable="fqForm" cssclass="button"/>
```

In Parts.xml

```
<composite name="edit-detail-finance-quotation" extends="new-detail-finance-quotation" layout="flow">
                    <part name="new-fq"  extends="implicit.child" >
                        <event name="fpTypeChanged"  target="parent.parent.new-finance-quotation" />
                        <event name="fpChanged"  target="parent.parent.new-finance-quotation" />
                        <event name="fcChanged"  target="parent.parent.new-finance-quotation" />
                        <event name="calculate"  target="parent.parent.new-finance-quotation" />
</composite>
```

In Java class

```
public ActionResult onCalculate(Request aRequest, AspectModel anAspectModel)
            throws Exception {
ActionResult theActionResult = ActionResult.SUCCEEDED;
        FqCalculationModel theModel = (FqCalculationModel) anAspectModel.get();
        HibernateService.getCurrentSession().lock(
                theModel.getProductQuotation(), LockMode.NONE);
        theModel = getModel(aRequest, anAspectModel, true);
// block of code performing logic

    return theActionResult;
    }
```